# Unity: Edit Gradle file of Android modules in Unity Assets

Tags: android, templates, unity-game-engine, gradle, module

I have a project with multiple Android modules and I would like to overwrite their gradle file. How can I accomplish that?

I am using the "mainTemplate.gradle" file for the main Android project and it works fine, but if I put this template inside my module, it's not used when building to Android project.

Comment: Where are you putting this file?

Comment: Inside my module, ie: Assets/Plugins/Android/mymodule/mainTemplate.gradle

I just discovered that I can rename it "build.gradle" and it works, but its not being parsed by Unity, so the stuff like \*\*SDKVERSION\*\* doesn't get replaced...

Answer (score 0):

You can only put `mainTemplate.gradle` in your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android` folder as this is where Unity hard-coded a way to look for the gradle file. If you put it anywhere else, it won't work since Unity can't find it. There are stuff you can't do inside Unity Editor and this is one of them.

The solution is to export your project and build it with Android Studio. By doing that, you can add as many gradle file as you want in your exported Android project.

Comment: Yes, for the main Android project I agree. But I have multiple modules inside that project. Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, I have my mainTemplate gradle file that contains ```compile project(':my-module')``` and I would like to edit the gradle file of 'my-module'.

Comment: Nope. You can't. You still have to export it out.